# Matching the end of line $ in perl; print showing different behavior with chomp

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading a file and matching a regex for lines with a hex number at the start followed by few dot separated hex values followed by optional array name which may contain an option index. For eg:

> 010c10  00000000.00000000.0000a000.02300000  myFooArray[0]

```
while (my $rdLine = <RDHANDLE>) {
  chomp $rdLine;

  if ($rdLine =~ m/^([0-9a-z]+)[ \t]+([0-9.a-z]+)[ \t]*([A-Za-z_0-9]*)\[*[0-9]*\]*$/) {
  ...
```

My source file containing these hex strings is also script generated. This match works fine for some files but other files produced thru the exact same script (ie no extra spaces, formats etc) do not match when the last $ is present on the match condition.
If I modify the condition to not have the end $, lines match as expected.

Another curious thing is for debugging this, I added a print statement like this:

```
if ($rdLine =~ m/^([0-9a-z]+)[ \t]+/) {
    print "Hey first part matched for $rdLine \n";
}   
if ($rdLine =~ m/^([0-9a-z]+)[ \t]+([0-9.a-z]+)/) {
    print "Hey second part matched for $rdLine \n";
}
```

The output on the terminal for the following input eats the first character :

> 010000                             00000000  foo

```
   "ey first part matched for 010000                             00000000  foo
    ey second part matched for 010000                             00000000  foo"
```

If I remove the chomp, it prints the Hey correctly instead of just ey.

Any clues appreciated!

Comment: Whats your `$/` set to ?

Comment: try pipe the output to `od -bc` and you probably will find the reason. `\r`

Comment: `chomp` isn't portable, so if you read files in different formats/from different platforms they might use different line endings. Use a regex to clean your data instead, like `$rdLine =~ s{[\f\n\r]*$}{};`. It cleans "Traditional Mac", Windows, and *nix/OSX line endings.

Comment: a hex character is `[0-9A-Fa-f]`, not `[0-9a-z]`. You could also use just `\p{hex}`

Comment: @jm666 - Thanks for the suggestion to try od -bc, the \r was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

> *"other files produced thru the exact same script (ie no extra spaces, formats etc) do not match when the last $ is present on the match condition"*

Although you deny it, I am certain that your file contains a single space character directly before the end of the line. You should check by using [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) to display the true contents of each file record. Like this

```
use Data::Dump;
dd \$read_line;
```

It is probably best to use

```
$read_line =~ s/\s+\z//;
```

in place of `chomp`. That will remove all spaces and tabs, as well as line endings like carriage-return and linefeed from the end of each line.

> *"If I remove the chomp, it prints the Hey correctly instead of just ey."*

It looks like you are working on a Linux machine, processing a file that was generated on a Windows platform. Windows uses the two characters CR LF as a record separator, whereas Linux uses just LF, so a `chomp` removes just the trailing LF, leaving CR to cause the start of the string to be overwritten.

If it wasn't for your secondary problem of having trailing whitespace, tThe best solution here would be to replace `chomp $read_line` with `$read_line =~ s/\R\z//`. The [`\R` character class](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/05/perlunicook-match-unicode-linebreak-sequence.html) matches the Unicode idea of a line break sequence, and was introduced in version 10 of Perl 5. However, the aforementioned `s/\s+\z//` will deal with your line endings as well, and should be all that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This was a  DOS file and it used the CR -LF at the end and that was the culprit as you mentioned. This was causing also the leading H to be removed in the print as the CR would take it to the beginning of the line and overwrite the H. The substitue you mentioned fixed the issue. Thanks also for the tip for hex detection.

Answer (score 0):

Borodin is right, \r\n is the culprit.

I used a less elegant solution, but it works:

```
$rdLine =~ s/\r//g;
```

followed by:

```
chomp $rdLine;
```